# How to create progress bar in html5, phonegap and jQuery

Tags: android, jquery, sql, html, cordova

I am creating a web app for android using html5, phonegap and jquery mobile. What I want to do is create a progress bar while running a function that inserts sql to database, informing the client how many has been done and how much is there left.

Can you please direct me how to start this? I already have the functions to connect and insert data to sql.

many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You might check out the new [progress tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp) in html5.
[This link](http://caniuse.com/#search=progress) will show you which mobile browsers support this tag.

Comment: wow, nice find. Definitely an excellent feature to look forward to for android

Answer (score 0):

Just like an above example, I have an improved one.

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

You can import the JS and CSS file given on the link above and then you can use the below code on Android WebApp.

```
    $(function() {

        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 10 });
        setTimeout(updateProgress, 500);

        });

        function updateProgress() {
          var progress;
          progress = $("#progressbar")
            .progressbar("option","value");
          if (progress < 100) {
              $("#progressbar")
                .progressbar("option", "value", progress + 5);
              setTimeout(updateProgress, 500);
          }
        }
```

This will move the progress with the increment of five after delay of half second. You can modify it as per the need.

Please let me know if this helps you

Kind Regards,

Summved

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar

Just use

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: ( STORED_DATA / TOTAL_DATA) });
```

For STORED_DATA, try to partition data sent to database ( while loop for example ).

Comment: am not sure if this will work on webapp for android.  But I believe they're making jQuery ui for mobile app soon.

Comment: I'd advise you to wait for that. The other solution is to load simple 20px*40px (vertical bar) and have that represent progress with the same ratio. ( STORED_DATA / TOTAL_DATA ) * (NUMBER_OF_VERTICAL_BARS_PER_100_PERCENT).

Comment: You don't want to add jQuery UI on top of jQuery Mobile, even just the progress bar as it is likely to create problems. I would recommend an animated gif instead.